# How to add options in MenuItem in .Net framework Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu

I have a context menu for notifyIcon, in which for one of the menu items I want to provide a submenu with three options that can be checked/unchecked. But I want this submenu to appear only when the user hovers/clicks over the arrow in the parent menu item. I.e., the user should be able to select the parent menu item without having to open its submenu, and the default values of the options in the submenu will be used in the parent menu's handler. Is this possible?

I am using Winforms with .Net framework 4.8.1 -

```
            MenuItem[] submenu = new MenuItem[]
            {
                new MenuItem("Italic",OpenItalic){ DefaultItem = true},
                new MenuItem("Bold",OpenBold),
                new MenuItem("Underline", OpenUnderline)
            };
            MenuItem[] menuItems = {
                new MenuItem("Show text", submenu)
            };
            icon = new NotifyIcon()
            {
                ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(menuItems),
                Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("instance.ico"),
                Visible = true,
                Text = "test"
            };
```

[image: context menu screenshot]

Here user has to select from the submenu items bold/italic/underline each time to open a form. Can we keep 'italic' as default option and allow the user to open the form by clicking 'Show text' option itself, and only open the submenu when there is a need to change the option?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: You could use the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 event and open the submenu when the mouse is over that control

Comment: I think that the submenu will always display. I suspect that you can implement an onclick handler for the top menu item (just as you would if there was no submenu item).